# If you meant to call the 'findOne' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists

Tags: mongodb, flask

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'findOne' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.

I tried `find_one()` and `findOne()`, both of them are returning the same error.
The project is designed in Python Flask. The logic is stuck here in the below line for ages...

```
            # bi=Binary(i)
            # i=i.rjust(24,'0')
            # print(i)

url_name=db_deeper_links.spider.findOne({"_id":ObjectId('000000016005788287649086')})
```

Comment: Are you using pymongo or mongoengine to access the database? Can show us the `db_deeper_links` variable; What is the error message when using `fine_one` ?

Answer (score 5):

It should be ***find_one()*** method if you are using Flask PyMongo. Check it again, for any spelling mistakes.